# Turning an array of seconds into a datetime array

Tags: python

I've got an array of seconds since the beginning of the year from a netCDF file and want to turn it into a datetime array. The time array is in units of seconds, every minute, i.e.:

```
timesec = ncfile['time'][:]

>>>timesec
0
60
120
180
240
300
360
420
...
```

And there is a basetime variable of the number of second since the begining of the year:

```
basetime = ncfile['base_time'][:]
>>>basetime
1457568000
```

basetime being March 10th at 12am.

How do I convert it into an array of format '2016-03-10 00:00:00' and the following minute being '2016-03-10 00:01:00' and so on. I'm sure there are many ways of doing it, but if you could recommend me one that'd be excellent.

Thank You!

Comment: What are the datatypes you are working with? What exact result do you want? String? Timestamp? What container? Numpy array? The same type as your input?

Answer (score 1):

Without any further information on the exact input and output format: You could just use a list comprehension to add the `basetime` to each of the seconds in `timesec`, then convert those to `datetime` using `fromtimestamp`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> timesec = [60*i for i in range(3)]
>>> basetime = 1457568000
>>> [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(basetime + s) for s in timesec]
[datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 10, 1, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 10, 1, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 10, 1, 2)]
```

You can convert those to `str`, which is pretty much the format you want, or use `isoformat` or `strftime` for other formats:

```
>>> [str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(basetime + s)) for s in timesec]
['2016-03-10 01:00:00', '2016-03-10 01:01:00', '2016-03-10 01:02:00']
```